# debug Javascript in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

This is a very general question. Is there a plugin to allow javascript debugging in Android Studio? Ive added javascript files to an assets folder that works with a webview that needs debugging. I know there is a plugin for eclipse but i can t find one for Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, Did you find any way to debug js files loaded in webView?